# Android Layout XML file not rendering and app craches after using material 3 Search view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, render, material-components-android

I'm fairly new to android and to material design in general I tried copying the code from material 3 search component but its doesn't render for some reason
I double checked the dependencies but everything seems right because I'm using 1.9.0-alpha02 version.

Here is the code that copied from MDC:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- NestedScrollingChild goes here (NestedScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/searchbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <!-- Screen content goes here. -->
  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint" />
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar">
    <!-- Search suggestions/results go here (ScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
  </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the entire code of my xml for more context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">




    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCompat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.FloatingActionButton.Circle"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_add_24" />

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- NestedScrollingChild goes here (NestedScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/searchbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                <!-- Screen content goes here. -->
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
                    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="" />
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint=""
                app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar">
                <!-- Search suggestions/results go here (ScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
            </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/mainRv"
            android:layout_width="346dp"
            android:layout_height="596dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.492"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:listitem="@layout/main_card">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to implement a search view from MDC 3:

````
```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- NestedScrollingChild goes here (NestedScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/searchbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <!-- Screen content goes here. -->
  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint" />
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar">
    <!-- Search suggestions/results go here (ScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
  </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>```
````

To try and use it later on but it didn't render in the xml file for some reason I tried fixing it for sometime but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you share the screen shot of xml layout of not rendering?

Comment: It should be ok after building the project. Check it after clicking "Make Project" button.